# How to return response of nested arrays with keys of same name in Laravel 5.*?

Tags: arrays, angular, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to implement treetable, using Laravel and Angular 4!

To achieve this task, after searching for good library supporting Treetable in Angular, I found, this library https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable for my needs.

I have integrated everything and it looks fine so far.

The only problem is when I use my APIs to get data coming from my backend, the primifaces treetable, is not recognizing my json structure coming from Laravel Api. The reason is because the library supports a different structure of Json.

Bellow is the Json structure which Primifaces support.

```
{
    "data":
    [  
        {  
            "data":{  
                "name":"Documents",
                "size":"75kb",
                "type":"Folder"
            },
            "children":[
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"Work",
                        "size":"55kb",
                        "type":"Folder"
                    },
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Expenses.doc",
                                "size":"30kb",
                                "type":"Document"
                            }
                        },
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Resume.doc",
                                "size":"25kb",
                                "type":"Resume"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"Home",
                        "size":"20kb",
                        "type":"Folder"
                    },
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Invoices",
                                "size":"20kb",
                                "type":"Text"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "data":{  
                "name":"Pictures",
                "size":"150kb",
                "type":"Folder"
            },
            "children":[  
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"barcelona.jpg",
                        "size":"90kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"primeui.png",
                        "size":"30kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"optimus.jpg",
                        "size":"30kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the json format which laravel returns from my apis looks like this.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uuid": 110,
      "name": "Acuzyt Tablets",
      "Parent_ID": 65,
      "ContentStart_ID": 20026,
      "children": [
        {
          "uuid": 275,
          "name": "Hansenf",
          "Parent_ID": 110,
          "ContentStart_ID": 22608,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "uuid": 111,
      "name": "Pluserix",
      "Parent_ID": 65,
      "ContentStart_ID": 24050,
      "children": [
        {
          "uuid": 276,
          "name": "Manuel",
          "Parent_ID": 111,
          "ContentStart_ID": 22609,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "uuid": 112,
      "name": "Abbott - Vancomycin",
      "Parent_ID": 65,
      "ContentStart_ID": 19944,
      "children": [
        {
          "uuid": 272,
          "name": "Mozaicos",
          "Parent_ID": 112,
          "ContentStart_ID": 22605,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "uuid": 113,
      "name": "Abic Leucovorin Sol",
      "Parent_ID": 65,
      "ContentStart_ID": 19946,
      "children": [
        {
          "uuid": 273,
          "name": "Hansenm Mangole",
          "Parent_ID": 113,
          "ContentStart_ID": 22606,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "uuid": 277,
          "name": "Mangole",
          "Parent_ID": 113,
          "ContentStart_ID": 22610,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "uuid": 114,
      "name": "Abic Vincristine",
      "Parent_ID": 65,
      "ContentStart_ID": 19947,
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

so when I use my Apis, Primifaces doesn't display the record value, I get undefined, on angular side.

The Laravel code which return my Apis look like this:

```
public function json(){
        $page = $this->request->get('page',1);
        $perPage = 5;
        $projects = Project::find(65);

        $childs = $projects->nestedProject($projects->uuid,$page, $perPage);

        return response()->json(['data'=>$childs->toArray()],201);
    }
```

And On Angular Side the Service looks like this.

```
getFileSystem(): any {
        return this.http.get('http://apiurl/api/v1/treetable')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <TreeNode[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }
```

And Component looks like this.

```
ngOnInit():void {
        this.nodeService.getFileSystem().then(data => this.data = data);
        let newdat = this.data;

        console.log(newdat);
        this.cols = [
        {field: 'uuid', header: 'Uuid'},
        {field: 'name',header: 'Name'},
        {field: 'Parent_ID', header: 'ParentID'},
        {field: 'ContentStart_ID', header: 'StartID'}
        ];
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to get json format from Laravel Backend to be the same as the primifaces.

If you take a look at both json you'll find that the json from primifaces got `data` for each json object.

Comment: You'll need to modify your json output, you can do this with a transformer. Check out http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/

Comment: okay let me check out the link